# How to permit single url in spring security

Tags: spring, http, spring-security, jwt

I have two get urls

> 1. /api/appconsole/app/{appid}
> 2. /api/appconsole/app/search

I want to secure second API but want to permit first one api.

below is the websecurityconfig.java file.
What should i write so that it will permit only 1st api i.e. /api/appconsole/app/{appid}

```
httpSecurity.csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()

                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/file/**/*.*",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/appconsole/app/{appid}").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/upload").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/orbeon/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding     antMatchers("/api/appconsole/app/search ").authenticated()

Comment: What HTTP method do you use for `/api/appconsole/app/search`? Doyou use `OPTION` or `GET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order matters:

```
http ...
   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/appconsole/app/search").authenticated()
   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/appconsole/app/*").permitAll()
```

Comment: yes, the order matters. Worked for me too